# Why is the `c` tag inappropriate for this question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I included the `c` tag in my [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145638/do-c-developers-commonly-count-on-implicit-casting/37145849), which user FUZxxl removed. I'm trusting that was correct given his reputation, but I don't understand why. It seems to me that the question applies to both C and C++.

Comment: If it seems to you that it applies to both C and C++ (and I agree with you), you can reverse the edit.

Comment: Not saying that this is the case here, but I've seen some people get offended when both C and C++ appear on the same question. Since your question mentions C++, I guess it sorta tipped the balance in favor of the C++ tag over the C tag.

Comment: You literally ask "Do C++ developers commonly count on automatic casting?".  You didn't ask "Do C++ and C developers..."

Comment: The Meta effect with downvotes in 3,2,1...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's inappropriate because your question is about C++. There is no such thing as "C/C++". If you have a question about C, ask it separately.